# How to run a command and let user interact with it i nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, command

I want to run a command and let user interact afterwards. Example, if i run `npm init`, the user should be able to give project name, description and all.. My current code just run the command and logs the output and terminates

My code:

```js
require('shelljs/global'); //npm/shelljs

var child = exec('npm initda', {async:true});
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

Output:

> This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file. It
> only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible
> defaults.
>
> See `npm help init` for definitive documentation on these fields and
> exactly what they do.
>
> Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and save it as
> a dependency in the package.json file.
>
> Press ^C at any time to quit. package name: (so-example)

Thanks in advance [this is not a duplicate question, it may look simmilar to my previos question :) ]

Comment: Why is it not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70906223/how-to-run-command-without-terminating-it-with-node-js? There both asking how to run commands in node without terminating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js how to show stdin input with child\_process.exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638008/node-js-how-to-show-stdin-input-with-child-process-exec)